# Splitting a string with different start delimeter (not a duplicate)

Tags: c++

I need to split a big string which contains substrings encapsulated by either !="" or !"" but I am stuck now.

The code I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    std::string line;

    // Create vector to store matrix
    std::vector< std::vector<string> > vec_line;
    // Create temp vector to create "rows"
    vector<string>vec_string_temp;


string add2vec_ele(string firste, string line)
{

    // Add row
    vec_string_temp.push_back(firste);
    boost::algorithm::split_regex( vec_string_temp, line, regex( "(!=\"|!\")" ) ) ;
    // store row in vec_line
    vec_line.push_back(vec_string_temp);
    vec_string_temp.clear();
return string();
}


int main()
{
    string firste = "KeyWord";
    string line = "!=\"abcd!#efg\" !\"ABCDEFGHAG!/8765438\" !\"This !/[isanotherstring]?but nobody cares78\" !=\"again a string with equal sign and exclamation mark\"";
    add2vec_ele(firste,line);

    // print all elements
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec_line.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Vector line: " << i << " ";
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < vec_line[i].size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << " Col: " << j << " " << vec_line[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
}
```

basically does what I want, except that the -> != <- or  -> !" <- are lost.

Input is stored in the string 'line'

```
string line = "!=\"abcd!#efg\" !\"ABCDEFGHAG!/8765438\" !\"This !/[isanotherstring]?but nobody cares78\" !=\"again a string with equal sign and exclamation mark\"";
```

The output from above code is

```
Vector line: 0  Col: 0  Col: 1 abcd!#efg"  Col: 2 ABCDEFGHAG!/8765438"  Col: 3 This !/[isanotherstring]?but nobody cares78"  Col: 4 again a string with equal sign and exclamation mark"
```

The expected output would be

```
Vector line: 0  Col: 0  Col: 1 !="abcd!#efg"  Col: 2 !"ABCDEFGHAG!/8765438"  Col: 3 !"This !/[isanotherstring]?but nobody cares78"  Col: 4 !="again a string with equal sign and exclamation mark"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would splitting on simply on `"!"` then an additional step of prepending `!` to all the result strings work for you?

Comment: Could you post a sample input, your current output of it and the expected output you want from it?

Comment: This is doable even with regex search - [`std::regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

Comment: @infixed: Unfortunately not since the substrings themself may contain exclamation marks as well. This would result in broken strings.

Comment: @FirstStep: The input is in the string 'line' (the code is executable), the sample output is as the expected output but the leading !=" or !" are missing.

Comment: @LogixStuff: Thanks. I will have a look into

Comment: I am not asking this just for myself, I am asking you to provide it IN your post for ALL readers. Do it and do it best to make it EASIER for readers to help you, if you are seeking good help provide good information.

Comment: @FirstStep: Done, thanks

Comment: Solved by using look ahead regex

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl Regex (look ahead) solved my issue:

```
string add2vec_ele(string firste, string line)
{
    // Add row
    vec_string_temp.push_back(firste);
    boost::regex ex( "(?<!^)(?:(?=!=\")|(?=!\"))", boost::regex::perl );
    boost::algorithm::split_regex( vec_string_temp, line, ex ) ;
    // store row in vec_line
    vec_line.push_back(vec_string_temp);
    vec_string_temp.clear();
return string();
}
```